# WP7 Bing map control is not movable when it is dragged slowly

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing, bing-maps

I used WP7 Bing map control to display the map. I want to do a precision drag on map. But when I dragged the map slowly (less than 4-5mm/ second), the map were not moving. I tried to use Bingmap application, and it had a good result - the map was moving when I dragged slowly. Is there anyway to make the Bing map control work fine like Bingmap application? Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set the CacheMode of your Map to BitmapCache, this should improve performance, as detailed in the following blog post :-

http://mindre.net/Article/windows_phone_7__cachemode_and_why_it_matters

Comment: Thank for your answer. The link was useful. But in my case, I hope find a way that I can move the map when I drag it slowly (4-5 millmetres/1 second) (Currently, the map doesn't move even a bit)